# Moving and Deleting Files in a Loop in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying to improve a system I have that already works. However I've ran into a problem I can't seem to find an answer to using google, perhaps I'm not searching the right questions?

I'm using a `For Each` loop to gather files in a directory. I then try to get each file name and some other information and determine if I should move the file temporarily or delete the file.

Example of the code used:

```
For Each File In Directory.GetFiles(Profile)

                    Dim tmpFile As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(File) 'Never moves to the next file.
                    Dim Name As String = tmpFile.Name

                    Dim AccessDate As String = tmpFile.LastWriteTime.Date()
                    Dim CurrentDate As String = My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.Date()

                    If AccessDate < CurrentDate Then
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(File) 'Moves to the next file without any issues.
                        Threading.Thread.Sleep(150) 'If no sleep program will lock up
                    Else

                        If Not Directory.Exists(Path) Then
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path)
                            My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(File, Path & Name)
                        Else
                            My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(File, Path & Name)
                        End If

                    End If

                Next
```

I have defined in the code what my problem is, and forgive me if there is a better way to do this, I'm self taught and still learning many things. If there's an easier way please point me in that direction.

Essentially I hit an error saying "File not found" on the move because `tmpFile` is not moving to the next `File` in the directory.

Comment: This code works without any problems for me. In which context do you use the code? Don't compare strings with `<`. Use `If AccessDate <> CurrentDate`. `MoveFile` already creates the folder if it does not exist. So you can leave that away.

Comment: @NicoSchertler actually the dataypes for these should be `Date` instead of `String`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. This was actually part of a much larger chunk of code and the error was coming from a 'For Each' loop that I didn't need in the first place. I suppose this is why you shouldn't write code when you're sleepy.